# Recursive uploading files using FtpWebRequest , BackgroundWorker in C#

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, ftpwebrequest

Using FtpWebRequest class and assign BackgroundWorker to upload the file. And working properly
but now I want to upload files from directory and their sub-directory.

I have created a component called - "FtpUploading" in which define private void function 
"FtpUploading_DoWork"

And same should be calling from a windows form application... If single file in directory then working file but if there is more than one file and sub-directory... it will not work.

```
    private void FtpUploading_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
            BackgroundWorker bw = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            FtpSettings ftpDet = e.Argument as FtpSettings;

            string UploadPath = String.Format("{0}/{1}{2}", ftpDet.Host, ftpDet.TargetFolder == "" ? "" : ftpDet.TargetFolder + "/", Path.GetFileName(ftpDet.SourceFile));
            if (!UploadPath.ToLower().StartsWith("ftp://"))
                UploadPath = "ftp://" + UploadPath;
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(UploadPath);
            request.UseBinary = true;
            request.UsePassive = ftpDet.Passive;
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpDet.Username, ftpDet.Password);

            long FileSize = new FileInfo(ftpDet.SourceFile).Length;
            string mFileName = new FileInfo(ftpDet.SourceFile).Name;
            string FileSizeDescription = GetFileSize(FileSize);
            int ChunkSize = 4096, NumRetries = 0, MaxRetries = 50;
            long SentBytes = 0;

            byte[] Buffer = new byte[ChunkSize];

            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                using (FileStream fs = File.Open(ftpDet.SourceFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                {
                    int BytesRead = fs.Read(Buffer, 0, ChunkSize);  
                    while (BytesRead > 0)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (bw.CancellationPending)
                                return;

                            requestStream.Write(Buffer, 0, BytesRead);
                            SentBytes += BytesRead;

                            string SummaryText = String.Format(mFileName + " => Transferred {0} / {1}", GetFileSize(SentBytes), FileSizeDescription);
                            bw.ReportProgress((int)(((decimal)SentBytes / (decimal)FileSize) * 100), SummaryText);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.ToString());
                            if (NumRetries++ < MaxRetries)
                            {
                                fs.Position -= BytesRead;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                throw new Exception(String.Format("Error occurred during upload, too many retries. \n{0}", ex.ToString()));
                            }
                        }
                        BytesRead = fs.Read(Buffer, 0, ChunkSize);  
                    }
                }
            }
            using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription));
        }


    public static string GetFileSize(long numBytes)
    {
        string fileSize = "";

        if (numBytes > 1073741824)
            fileSize = String.Format("{0:0.00} Gb", (double)numBytes / 1073741824);
        else if (numBytes > 1048576)
            fileSize = String.Format("{0:0.00} Mb", (double)numBytes / 1048576);
        else
            fileSize = String.Format("{0:0} Kb", (double)numBytes / 1024);

        if (fileSize == "0 Kb")
            fileSize = "1 Kb";  // min.                         
        return fileSize;
    }
```

//calling function

```
        private void recursiveDirectory(string dirPath, string uploadPath)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dirPath, "*.*");
        string[] subDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(dirPath);
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            if (this.ftpUploading1.IsBusy)
            {
               // this.ftpUploading1.CancelAsync();
               // this.btnFtp.Text = "Upload";
                Thread.Sleep(50);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                ftpSet.TargetFolder = uploadPath;
                ftpSet.SourceFile = file;
                this.toolStripProgressBar1.Visible = true;
                this.ftpUploading1.RunWorkerAsync(ftpSet);
                this.btnFtp.Text = "Cancel";
            }
        }
        foreach (string subDir in subDirs)
        {
            ftpClient.createDirectory(uploadPath + "/" + Path.GetFileName(subDir));
            recursiveDirectory(subDir, uploadPath + "/" + Path.GetFileName(subDir));
        }
    }
```

Comment: "it will not work" is not a very good problem report. Include full error messages and/or describe what actually happens vs expected.

Comment: It upload single file only and if I did't check IsBusy then "This BackgroundWorker is currently busy and cannot run multiple tasks concurrently." And I want after completing first task next task will be assign. New task will be assign after "ftpUploading1_RunWorkerCompleted" message.

Answer (score 0):

You check for `IsBusy` immediately after starting the aync task, and if it's `true`, you break the loop which of nearly always is. This what happening.

Removing that condition will lead to the error you mentioned in comments. So you should either wait for the task to be completed, or implement a loop inside the `FtpUploading_DoWork`.

And the third (and best) option is to use a `Task`. `Task` supports `ContinueWith()` which is exactly what you need.

I will explain the first solution here, because it needs very little changes on your existing code. Also this is just to give you a glimpse of the synchronization process. You will probably need to polish the code further.

You need a `WaitHandle`, for `FtpUploading_DoWork` to tell `recursiveDirectory` when it is finished its job. We will use `ManualResetEvent` for this matter. Once you `Reset` the ManualResetEvent, it will wait on a call to `WaitOne` until another thread calls `Set` on that same ManualResetEvent.

So back to work, Add a `ManualResetEvent` to your class:

```
System.Threading.ManualResetEvent waitForUpload = new 
                               System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false);
```

Change the first `for` inside `recursiveDirectory`:

```
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        ftpSet.TargetFolder = uploadPath;
        ftpSet.SourceFile = file;
        this.toolStripProgressBar1.Visible = true;

        waitForUpload.Reset();
        this.ftpUploading1.RunWorkerAsync(ftpSet);
        this.btnFtp.Text = "Cancel";

        waitForUpload.WaitOne();
        while (this.ftpUploading1.IsBusy)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100); // This is for the case if the WaitHandle is Set
                               // but the BackgroundWorker is still busy, 
                               // which should not take so long
        }
    }
```

And change `FtpUploading_DoWork`:

```
private void FtpUploading_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
         // Existing code inside the method
    }
    finally
    {
        waitForUpload.Set();
    }
}
```